# My scroll to top button not showing when scrolling

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to implement a "Scroll to top" function on my website. Simply what I have is a button with some JS to make it apear when scrolling and when clicked scroll the user to the top automatically and then disapear. My problem is that the button is not showing when I am scrolling. I also made a parallax hero image thing and I think it was after that the button stopped working.

I would need some help on why the button isn't showing on scroll and how I can fix it. Here is the HTML, css and JS which I think is causing the trouble. I'll include an entire snippet below.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  // Hamburger
  $(".burger-container").click(function () {
    $(".nav-menu").toggleClass("menu-opened");
    $("body").toggleClass("unscrollable");
  });

  // Dark-Light switcher
  $("body").toggleClass("light", localStorage.toggled == "light");

  document.getElementById("checkBox").addEventListener("click", darkLight);

  function darkLight() {
    if (localStorage.toggled != "light") {
      $("body").toggleClass("light", true);
      localStorage.toggled = "light";
    } else {
      $("body").toggleClass("light", false);
      localStorage.toggled = "";
    }
  }

  if ($("body").hasClass("light")) {
    $("#checkBox").prop("checked", true);
  } else {
    $("#checkBox").prop("checked", false);
  }
});

// Scroll to top
button = document.getElementById("scroll-button");

button.addEventListener("click", topFunction);

window.onscroll = function () {
  scrollFunction();
};

function scrollFunction() {
  if (document.body.scrollTop > 20 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 20) {
    button.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    button.style.display = "none";
  }
}

function topFunction() {
  window.scrollTo({
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
    behavior: "smooth",
  });
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* Dark colors */
:root {
  --white-color: #d9d9d9;
  --black-color: #0d0d0d;

  --grey-color-1: #595959;

  --body-bg-color: #262626;

  --text-hover-color: #a6a6a6;
}

/* Light colors */
:root .light {
  --body-bg-color: #dfdfdf;

  --black-color: blue;
  --white-color: black;
}

/* ======== MAIN CSS ======== */

html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;

  background-color: var(--body-bg-color) !important;

  position: relative;

  overflow: hidden;

  font-family: "Nunito", sans-serif;
  color: var(--white-color);
}

main {
  background-color: var(--body-bg-color);
}

.wrapper {
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  perspective: 10px;
}

.top {
  z-index: 999;

  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;

  width: 100%;

  transition: 0.5s ease;
}

nav {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 999;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 3.5rem;
  background-color: var(--black-color);
}

.unscrollable {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.active {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

/* ======= PARALLAX ======= */

.parallax {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  z-index: -1;
}

.background {
  transform: translateZ(-10px) scale(2);
  -webkit-user-drag: none;
  user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
}

.foreground {
  transform: translateZ(-5px) scale(1.5);
  -webkit-user-drag: none;
  user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
}

.background,
.foreground {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  z-index: -1;
}

.hero-text {
  text-align: center;
  color: var(--white-color);

  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;

  min-width: 14rem;

  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.hero-text > h1 {
  font-size: 3rem;
}

.hero-text > p {
  font-size: 1rem;
}

/* ======== HAMBURGER ======== */

.burger-container {
  position: absolute;
  right: 1rem;
  top: 0.1rem;

  display: inline-block;

  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;

  transform: rotate(0deg);
  transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.01, 0.165, 0.99);
  user-select: none;

  z-index: 999;

  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
}

#burger {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;

  width: 18px;
  height: 8px;

  display: block;

  margin: -4px auto 0;
}

.bar {
  position: relative;

  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;

  display: block;

  background: var(--white-color);

  transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.01, 0.165, 0.99);
  transition-delay: 0s;
}

.topBar {
  transform: translateY(0px) rotate(0deg);
}

.btmBar {
  transform: translateY(6px) rotate(0deg);
}

.menu {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;

  padding: 0;
  background: var(--black-color);
  height: 100%;

  list-style: none;
}

.menu-item {
  transform: translateY(-200px);
  transition: transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.01, 0.165, 1);
}

.menu-item a {
  display: block;
  position: relative;

  color: var(--white-color);
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 1.3rem;
  line-height: 2.35;

  border-bottom: 1px solid var(--body-bg-color);

  width: 100%;
}

.menu-item a:hover {
  color: var(--text-hover-color);
  text-decoration: none;
}

.nav-menu {
  height: 3.5rem;
  transition: height 0.4s;
}

.nav-menu.menu-opened {
  transition: height 0.4s;

  position: absolute;
  top: 0;

  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}

.nav-menu.menu-opened .burger-container {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}

.nav-menu.menu-opened .burger-container #burger .bar {
  transition: all 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.01, 0.165, 0.99);
  transition-delay: 0.2s;
}

.nav-menu.menu-opened .burger-container #burger .bar.topBar {
  transform: translateY(4px) rotate(45deg);
}

.nav-menu.menu-opened .burger-container #burger .bar.btmBar {
  transform: translateY(3px) rotate(-45deg);
}

.nav-menu.menu-opened ul.menu li.menu-item {
  transform: scale(1) translateY(0px);
}

/* ======== Dark Light switcher ====== */

.switcher > span {
  color: var(--white-color);
  padding: 0 0.5rem;
  font-size: 1.3rem;
}

.switcher {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.toggler-container {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 1rem;
  transform: translateY(-200px);
  transition: transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.01, 0.165, 1);
}

.nav-menu.menu-opened ul.menu li.toggler-container {
  transform: scale(1) translateY(0px);
}

.switch {
  position: relative;
  align-self: center;

  display: inline-block;

  width: 3.2rem;
  height: 1.5rem;
}

.switch input {
  opacity: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}

.slider {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;

  cursor: pointer;

  background-color: #808080;

  -webkit-transition: 0.4s;
  transition: 0.4s;

  border-radius: 1rem;
}

.slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  left: 4px;
  bottom: 4px;

  content: "";

  height: 1rem;
  width: 1rem;

  background-color: var(--white-color);

  -webkit-transition: 0.4s;
  transition: 0.4s;

  border-radius: 50%;
}

input:checked + .slider {
  background-color: #808080;
}

input:checked + .slider:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(1.7rem);
  -ms-transform: translateX(1.7rem);
  transform: translateX(1.7rem);
}

/* ======== CONTENT ======= */

.content {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 5% 0 5%;
  padding-top: 1.5rem;
  color: var(--white-color);
}

.content h2 {
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
}

.content p {
  font-size: 1.1rem;
  font-family: "Nunito", sans-serif;
}

.img {
  display: block;
}

/* ======== UP ARROW ========*/

#scroll-button {
  display: none;

  position: fixed;
  bottom: 1rem;
  right: 1.2rem;

  z-index: 998;

  border: none;
  outline: none;

  background-color: transparent;
  color: var(--white-color);
  font-size: 1.5rem;

  cursor: pointer;

  border-radius: 50%;
}

/* ======== FOOTER ======== */

footer {
  padding: 3rem 0 6rem 0;
  background-color: var(--grey-color-1);
  position: sticky;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: -2;
}

footer ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.3rem;
}

footer ul a {
  color: var(--white-color);
  text-decoration: none;
}

footer ul li {
  display: block;
  padding: 0.25rem 0;
}

footer ul a:hover {
  color: var(--text-hover-color);
}

footer hr {
  color: var(--text-hover-color);
  max-width: 13rem;
  margin: 1.5rem auto;
}

footer .copyright {
  margin-top: 1rem;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 0.75rem;
  color: var(--text-hover-color);
}

/* ======== MEDIA QUERIES ======== */

/* TABLET */
@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  /* ======= FOOTER ======= */
  footer ul {
    font-size: 1.1rem;
  }

  footer ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 0.2rem;
  }

  footer hr {
    max-width: 35rem;
  }
}

/* DESKTOP */
@media only screen and (min-width: 769px) {
  /* ======== MAIN CSS ======== */

  .top {
    overflow: hidden;
  }

  .hero-text {
    position: absolute;
    top: 40%;
    left: 30%;
    max-width: 20rem;
  }

  .hero-text > h1 {
    font-size: 3.5rem;
  }

  .hero-text > p {
    font-size: 1.2rem;
  }

  /* ======= Scrollbar ======== */
  ::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 7px;

    background: transparent;
  }

  ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    border-radius: 100px;

    background: rgb(109, 109, 109);
  }

  ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
    background-color: rgb(148, 148, 148);
  }

  /* ======== HAMBURGER ======== */
  nav {
    width: 100%;

    background-color: var(--black-color);
    backdrop-filter: none;
  }

  .nav-menu {
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in, 0.5s ease-in;
    transition-delay: 0.25s;

    width: 100%;
    height: 3.5rem;

    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
  }

  .nav-menu.menu-opened {
    height: 100%;
  }

  .burger-container {
    display: none;
  }

  .menu-item {
    transform: scale(1) translateY(0px);

    display: inline;

    margin-right: 0.8rem;
    border-bottom: 0;
    margin-top: 0;
  }

  .menu {
    flex-direction: row;

    position: absolute;
    top: 0;

    margin: 0 0 0 1.5rem;

    height: 3.5rem;
    width: 100%;
  }

  .menu-item a {
    display: inline;

    border: none;

    font-size: 1rem;

    transition: all 0.15s cubic-bezier(0.54, 0.12, 0.54, 0.94);
  }

  .flex-filler {
    flex: 1 1 auto;
  }

  /* ======== Dark-light switcher ======== */

  .toggler-container {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 2.5rem 0 0;
    transform: scale(1) translateY(0px);
  }

  .switcher > span {
    font-size: 1.2rem;

    padding: 0 0.4rem;
  }

  .switch {
    width: 2.5rem;
    height: 1.3rem;
  }

  .slider:before {
    height: 0.8rem;
    width: 0.8rem;

    left: 4px;
    bottom: 4px;
  }

  input:checked + .slider:before {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(1.2rem);
    -ms-transform: translateX(1.2rem);
    transform: translateX(1.2rem);
  }

  /* ======== CONTENT ========*/

  .content {
    margin: 0 20% 0 20%;
    padding-top: 2rem;
  }

  .content h2 {
    font-size: 1.5rem;
  }

  .content p {
    font-size: 1.15rem;
  }

  /* ======== UP ARROW ========*/

  #scroll-button {
    position: fixed;

    height: 3rem;
    width: 3rem;

    bottom: 1.1rem;
    right: 1.1rem;
  }

  #scroll-button:hover {
    background-color: rgba(160, 160, 160, 0.568);
    backdrop-filter: blur(15px);
  }

  /* ======= FOOTER ======= */
}

/* XL-DESKTOP */
@media only screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
  /* ======= HAMBURGER ======= */

  .menu-item {
    margin-right: 1.3rem;
  }

  .menu-item a {
    font-size: 1.1rem;
  }

  /* ======= FOOTER ======= */
  footer ul {
    font-size: 1.2rem;
  }

  footer ul li {
    padding: 0 0.4rem;
  }

  footer hr {
    max-width: 40rem;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="sv">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Lagar och säkerhet | Hem</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:ital,wght@0,100;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,700;0,900;1,100;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,700;1,900&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Nunito:ital,wght@0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;0,900;0,1000;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700;1,800;1,900;1,1000&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <link
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css"
    />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Material+Symbols+Outlined:opsz,wght,FILL,GRAD@48,400,0,0"
    />
    <script defer src="js/script.js"></script>
  </head>
  <!--
    Att göra: 
    
    Fixa bilder till Hero parallax
    Skriva content
    Fixa bilder till content (Picture element, bootstrap)
    Lägga in all content på index och subpages (Bootstrap)
    Fixa up arrow så den funkar
    Tablet responsive media query
    Hamburger close animation (Inte prio)
  -->
  <body>
    <div class="top">
      <nav>
        <div class="nav-menu">
          <div class="burger-container">
            <div id="burger">
              <div class="bar topBar"></div>
              <div class="bar btmBar"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <ul class="menu">
            <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Hem</a></li>
            <li class="menu-item"><a href="html/losenord.html">Lösenord</a></li>
            <li class="menu-item">
              <a href="html/sakerhetshot.html">Säkerhetshot</a>
            </li>
            <li class="menu-item">
              <a href="html/statlig-kontroll.html">Statlig kontroll</a>
            </li>
            <li class="menu-item">
              <a href="html/tredjepartskod.html">Tredjepartskod</a>
            </li>
            <li class="menu-item">
              <a href="html/webbhotell.html">Webbhotell</a>
            </li>
            <div class="flex-filler"></div>
            <li class="toggler-container">
              <div class="switcher">
                <span class="material-symbols-outlined"> dark_mode </span>
                <label class="switch">
                  <input type="checkbox" id="checkBox" />
                  <span class="slider"></span>
                </label>
                <span class="material-symbols-outlined"> light_mode </span>
              </div>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </div>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <header class="parallax">
        <img src="https://cdn.imgpaste.net/2022/10/10/Kem93m.png" class="background" />
        <img src="https://cdn.imgpaste.net/2022/10/10/KemO9N.png" class="foreground" />
        <div class="hero-text">
          <h1>Lagar och säkerhet</h1>
          <p>
            Hemsidan om lagar och säkerhet på internet här står det massa saker wow omg coolt :I
          </p>
        </div>
      </header>
      <main>
        <div class="content">
          <section>
            <h2>Hejehje</h2>
            <p>
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Magni in aut quisquam ipsa,
              reiciendis quidem rem facilis quaerat nam est! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur,
              adipisicing elit. Libero, nulla perferendis? Officia illo vitae alias obcaecati nulla
              porro quisquam, praesentium id vel ex culpa deleniti neque reiciendis officiis nisi
              quaerat.
            </p>
          </section>
          <picture class="img">
            <source media="(min-width: 900px)" srcset="imgs/template1000.jpg" />
            <img src="imgs/template500.jpg" alt="template500" />
          </picture>
        </div>
        <button id="scroll-button" title="Gå till toppen">
          <i class="fas fa-arrow-up"></i>
        </button>
      </main>
      <footer>
        <ul class="list">
          <li>
            <a href="#" class="active">Hem</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="html/losenord.html">Lösenord</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="html/sakerhetshot.html">Säkerhetshot</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="html/statlig-kontroll.html">Statlig kontroll</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="html/tredjepartskod.html">Tredjepartskod</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="html/webbhotell.html">Webbhotell</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <hr />
        <p class="copyright">Copyright &copy; All rights reserved by Vincent Cornelius</p>
      </footer>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`document.body.scrollTop` is 0.
From [Mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollTop):

> If the element can't be scrolled (e.g. it has no overflow or if the element has a property of "non-scrollable"), scrollTop is 0.

Use `window.scrollY` instead.

Sample code:

```js
window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
  if (window.scrollY > 250) {
    button.style.display = 'block';
  } else {
    button.style.display = 'none';
  }
});
```